# Saving Deleted Rows To Core Data Error - Swift 3

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data

I posted a post similar to this but my question was half answered. I would like to be able to swipe to delete rows but then save that data to my xcdatamodeld file. I have an attribute in xcdatamodeld called removeTask but that is as far as I got. Any help appreciated

```
//Removing Tasks
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete {

        // 1)
        let task = tasks.remove(at: indexPath.row)

        // 2)
        saveToCoreData(task: task)

        // 3)
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }
}



func saveToCoreData(task: Task) {

    do {
        try managedObjectContext.save()
    } catch {
        fatalError("Failure to save context: \(error)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to delete the object in the data source array **and** in the Core Data stack:

```
// 1)
let task = tasks.remove(at: indexPath.row)
managedObjectContext.delete(task)

// 2)
saveToCoreData(task: task)

// 3)
tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
```

A side note:

- `beginUpdates() / endUpdates()` is not needed at all for a single delete operation.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Insert Into CoreData (very important)
let managedObject = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "removedTask", into: self.managedObjectContext)

// assign values
managedObject.value = task.value
```

These operations are the source of *ambiguity*. 
When `saveToCoreData` is invoked from `commit editingStyle:`, it's sole purpose is to pass down the changes made in context to the persistent store.
By performing `NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject`, a new object is being created in context which is absolutely not the intent here.

Modifying the `saveToCoreData` as follows will help:

```
func saveToCoreData(task: Task) {

    do {
        try managedObjectContext.save()
    } catch {
        fatalError("Failure to save context: \(error)")
    }

    // for updating tasks array with the latest data set
    let tasksFetch = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Task") // "Task" or whatever is the actual name of entities stored in tasks array

    do {
        tasks = try managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(tasksFetch) as! [Task]
    } catch {
        fatalError("Failed to fetch task: \(error)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have modified my _saveToCoreData_ but when I delete the row, it comes back after i switch views then come back to the main view. Any ideas? @ystack

Comment: @LukeRoberts Ensure that the array (or dictionary) used to populate the table is updated with the latest changes. Basically, after swiping to delete & saving to context, you also need to do a database fetch request to get the latest content. This fetch request should be used to update the array consumed by table.

Comment: I was kind of unsure how to do this... I'll update the question. sorry @ystack

Comment: okay, no problem, can you share the table `numberOfRows` implementation ?

Comment: @LukeRoberts as expected from your edit, the `tasks` needs to be updated by a core data fetch request after deletion of any object (from swipe to delete). Check the edited answer, a good place to update the `tasks` array is when any change (like deletion here) happens in database

Comment: Every time I swipe to delete, I get a crash. Also the code that was written had errors and xcode fixed them for me. Not sure what the problem is here @ystack